# Adding data to AJAX request using UJS, Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I have a text_field_tag with a link_to:

```
<div>
  <%= text_field_tag :requester_field %>
  <%= link_to "Add", add_requester_tasks_path, id: "requester_btn", remote: true %>
</div>
```

Using rails UJS clicking Add button will trigger AJAX request to controller action specified by add_requester_task_path. Where I can return a script back to browser using respond_to block.

**What will be the best way to add value of the text_field to this request?**

So I can access it in the controller via params hash.

By the best way I mean the cleanest way, using UJS. I have looked at some ajax:callbacks but I can't figure out the way to add a data to the request.

I am using coffee script for JS.
This code is part of the bigger form that creates a task. Task has_many requesters. This code will populate a list of requesters based on email address entered into a text field. Submitting a form will link requesters to the task. Thats why I can't use a form inside the form.

Comment: Tip for stackoverflow: to format your text into a block of code, select the relevant text and press ctrl+k (or add 4 blank spaces before each line of the block). If you want "inline" piece of code, use the backticks `

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a form?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thank you. I tried with 4 spaces but it didn't like div so I decided to use the code syntax. I didn't know about ctrl+k

Comment: Create your own ajax request and the task is trivial if the plugin docs don't provide enough support

Comment: @charlietfl thats 100% correct. And it is a valid way of doing it. It is just good to know how to do it the other way as well.

Comment: Judging by the very thin docs for that plugin ... will most likely be the fastest. Can also read the source code for plugin

Answer (score 1):

Following on charlietfl suggestion I have looked at UJS source code(which end up being extremely short...).

I have come up with this solution:

You need to have **remote: true** on your link to enable UJS.

You need to add this code to your js/coffee file(code assume turbolinks for DOM ready)

```
ready = -> 
  $("#requester_btn").on "ajax:before", (event, xhr, settings) -> 
    $(this).data('params', $("#requester_field").serialize()) 
    return

$(document).on("page:change", ready)
```

Adding data-params to the link with the serialized value of the text_field will let UJS do its magic.